# displayScore function not being called onto Results page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I need to be able to call the displayScore function to the results page but I get nothing, all it says for me is that displayScore isn't defined I'm very new to javascript and am just lost at this point to what I'm doing wrong. I have to write this quiz without using localstorage and need the score and questions with which questions were right or wrong on the results page.

```
const quizQuestions = [ 

  { 
      "question": "Q1. What animal is at the top of the food chain?", 
      "answers":["Tiger", "Parrot", "Rabbit"], 
      "correctAnswer": 0,
     
  
  },
  {
      "question":"Q2. Which animal is closely related to Human-kind?",
      "answers":["Dolphin", "Monkey", "Rat"],
      "correctAnswer": 1,
      
  },
  {
      "question":"Q3. What animal lives the longest?",
      "answers": ["Tortoise","Gold Fish","Snake"],
      "correctAnswer": 0,
      
  },
  {
      "question":"Q4. How Far Could a Wolf Smell You From?",
      "answers": ["4 miles", "10 miles","2 miles"],
      "correctAnswer": 2,
      
  },
  {
      "question":"Q5. What Animal Has the Strongest Shell?",
      "answers":["Armadilla","Turtle","Sea Snail"],
      "correctAnswer": 2,
      
  }];
  
  function checkAnswer(questionNumber) {
    var chosenAnswer = "";
    a = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      if (a[i].checked) {
        chosenAnswer = a[i].value;
      }
    }
    if (chosenAnswer == quizQuestions[questionNumber]["answers"][quizQuestions[questionNumber]["correctAnswer"]]) {
      quizQuestions[questionNumber]["correct"] = true;
    } else {
      quizQuestions[questionNumber]["correct"] = false;
    }
  
  }
  
  function loadQuestion(questionNumber) {
      //Resets question correctness if the first question is loaded
      if (questionNumber == 0) {
          for (i = 0; i < quizQuestions.length; i++) {
              quizQuestions[i]["correct"] = false;
          }
      }
      q = document.getElementById("question");
      q.innerHTML = quizQuestions[questionNumber]["question"];
  }
  
  
  
  function displayScore() {
      score = 0
      for (i = 0; i < quizQuestions.length; i++) {
          if (quizQuestions[i]["correct"] == true) {
              score += 1
          }
      }
      scoreDisplay = document.querySelector('#score');
      scoreDisplay.innerHTML = score;

      
  }
```

Thats my javascript

Here's one of the question.html pages

```
type her<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body onload="loadQuestion(0)">

  <h1>Question 1</h1>
  <div id="questionBox">
  <p id="question"></p>

  <input type="radio" name="answer" id="tiger" value ="Tiger" required>
  <label for="Tiger">Tiger</label>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" id="parrot" value="Parrot">
  <label for="Parrot">Parrot</label>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" id="rabbit" value="Rabbit">
  <label for="Rabbit">Rabbit</label>
 <br>
  <a href="Q2.html">
  <button type="button" onclick="checkAnswer(0)">Next</button>
  </a>
  </div>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <script src="quiz.js"></script>

</body>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
   
  <p>Your score is: <span id="score"></span></p>
  <script>displayScore();</script>

    <script src="quiz.js"> </script>
</body>
```

this is the results page

I've tried to write the function different and also check if maybe it was just my quizQuestions was defined wrong but no, I'm completely lost.

Comment: Where is your displayScore function located?

Comment: hey it's inside the first set of code with the scroll bar That's the javascript!

Comment: displayScore couldn't be found because it's being called before the **quiz.js** script is imported.

Answer (score 1):

`quiz.js` is loaded after you attempt to call `displayScore`. You just need to flip the order of the imports.

```
<script src="quiz.js"> </script>
<script>displayScore();</script>
```

Comment: OMG THANK YOU i know this might be a big question to ask but is there any specific reason in my code why it's not counting the questions I got right? the score is always 0. No matter what. As well as never displaying the question length so instead of saying 0/5 it only says 0